# Error: We don't have a valid access azure with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm a newer user of Azure CLI.  So, i started to used it yesterday.  Everything was ok until I received a message on the console that I need to login again, using the command Azure login.

I did that the message say.  Open my browser and enter the code. The browser load the page that every things it's ok.  But, when i go to the console window I receive these message:

```
error:   We don't have a valid access token. Please run "azure login" again.
info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\julia\.azure\azure.err
error:   login command failed

on the detail error file, this is the content:
2015-12-09T14:25:39.477Z - info:    Executing command login
2015-12-09T14:25:40.278Z - info:    To sign in, use a web browser to open the page aka.ms/devicelogin. Enter the code FYEBRSSSW to authenticate. If you're signing in as an Azure AD application, use the --username and --password parameters.
2015-12-09T14:25:40.278Z - verbose: code response from AAD is :{"userCode":"FYEBRSSSW","deviceCode":"FAAABAAEAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLSP06OmChH0nnUbKKbL9_GLsujCsreUiKWZtv3DBNS6o5dK7vblnGRAk_b_3oO64FJ9f6Dd306_5P_ZlMUwIPCD-a02NydqTyYXXXXXXX","verificationUrl":"aka.ms/devicelogin","expiresIn":900,"interval":5,"message":"To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://aka.ms/devicelogin. Enter the code FYEBRSSSW to authenticate. If you're signing in as an Azure AD application, use the --username and --password parameters."}
2015-12-09T14:36:25.449Z - error:   We don't have a valid access token. Please run "azure login" again.
2015-12-09T14:36:25.451Z - silly:   {
2015-12-09T14:36:25.451Z - silly:       stack: "Error: We don't have a valid access token. Please run "azure login" again.\n    at _polishError (C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\adalAuthForUser.js:64:10)\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\adalAuthForUser.js:48:25\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\token-cache.js:96:9\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:52:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:272:32\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:44:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\win-token-storage.js:169:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:697:13\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:52:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:272:32",
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:       message: "We don't have a valid access token. Please run "azure login" again.",
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:       __frame: {
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           name: '__1',
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           line: 47,
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           file: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\commands\\login.js',
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           prev: undefined,
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           calls: 0,
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           active: false,
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           offset: 53,
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:           col: 27
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:       },
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:       rawStack: " token. Please run "azure login" again.\n    at _polishError (C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\adalAuthForUser.js:64:10)\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\adalAuthForUser.js:48:25\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\token-cache.js:96:9\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:52:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:272:32\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:44:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\lib\\util\\authentication\\win-token-storage.js:169:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:697:13\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:52:16\n    at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:272:32"
2015-12-09T14:36:25.452Z - silly:   }
2015-12-09T14:36:25.458Z - info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\julia\.azure\azure.err
```

When i join to the portal, everything it is alright,  my account is active, i can create and monitore all my machines without problem. It's a particular situation with de Azure CLI v2.8.

By the way,  i try the "azure logout and azure clear -q"  commands without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens if you have multiple azure accounts. I mean this is a **browser->cache/cookies** problem.

You should open a private browser session, or even use another browser and start a fresh session there using the link provided by the console CLI.

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

There is other alternative issue solution if the first doesn't resolver your problem.  You can go to the ***windows credential manager***.  In the **Windows Credential** tab, **delete** the credetial storaged of Microsoft, like Microsoft_PaidWifi_MicroRefreshToken or someone that have login.microsoftonline.com....

I did that deleting the credentials with date near to my problem.  Now i can loggin on azure cli without problem.

[image]
julian

Comment: I facing same problem but on my ubuntu machine. First solution doesn't worked for me.